# How to deploy python projects without storing config files on GitHub?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, github, configuration, continuous-deployment

*[Old Title: Publish Python/Flask app to Google App Engine using GitHub actions, without storing configuration on GitHub]*

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this.

I'm looking for the correct way to automate my workflow.

I have the following:

1. Develop code locally.

   - Configuration is stored in .env file and some other .json too.
2. Push to GitHub develop branch.

   - GitHub does not have any configuration except for the empty 'default' config.
3. On push (PR) into master, a build is kicked off, and it automatically publishes to Google Cloud (App Engine).

   - *(This is probably wrong)* - I have GitHub action that builds the .env from GitHub secrets before deployment.

What I originally thought was that I could manually upload the correct configuration files onto the server (App Engine) in this case but I didn't see an option to manually upload files, hence I decided to include them in the deployment process using GitHub action and GitHub secrets (but it's annoying to do).

What is the correct way to handle configurations without making them public on GitHub?

Thanks in advance!

Jakub.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Ignoring files for your repo. you can refer to [Github Documentation Ignoring files](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/ignoring-files).

You can set all the configuration files to be ignored.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I have that already. The question is more on how can I deploy configuration files to Google App Engine. (Because as you said, configuration is NOT on GitHub, hence it's not deployed with the project, hence I need to manually (somehow) deploy config to App Engine). Or perhaps my entire workflow / understanding is wrong.

Comment: App engine  configuration should be included in the [app.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml). Can you be more specific about your workflow  or understanding about the configuration ?